# AndroidPlot: how does it fit together

Tags: android, androidplot

I am using AndroidPlot to create a simple bar graphing app that displays some values in real time. I just started using it, so bear with me. There is a tutorial, which gives some basic info and then there are the JavaDocs that seem to give me everything including the kitchen sink.

My question now is: how do all the AndroidPlot classes fit together? I have a Plot, a Formatter and a Renderer, but I don't seem to find a way to create a Renderer.

(to be a little more precise: I want a bar graph with bars that have some width and different colours per bar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found it out, it is not easily found in the docs. I found it here: https://androidplot.jira.com/source/browse/ANDROIDPLOT/trunk/Examples/DemoApp/src/com/androidplot/demos/OrientationSensorExampleActivity.java?hb=true

There is an `XYPlot` object (as found in the quickstart), where you can add a `XYSeries` to. The `XYSeries`, as well as a `Formatter`. To get the `Renderer`, you will need to tell that to the `AddSeries` method call. Then, with the `getRenderer` call and some casting, you can get the `Renderer`, where you can throw in some renderer-specific stuff.

In code:

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.myPlot);
XYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(
      Arrays.asList(new Number[] { 1,2,3 } ), 
      SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "title");
BarFormatter formatter = new BarFormatter(
           Color.rgb(0, 200, 0),
           Color.rgb(100, 0, 0));
plot.addSeries(series, BarRenderer.class, formatter);
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer)plot.getRenderer(BarRenderer.class);

// the BarRenderer is available now
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to do a simple bar graph but with no success. I did see the example you linked but I am still missing something, do you happen to have a basic example please?